# Use grep to search the matching string but search should show only the rest of string without the matched word

Tags: grep

I have a different scenario. To make it more clear here is what I want.

I've a file named `myfile` with following info:

```
Saurav Kumar
    Sumeet Kumar
Punit Kumar Sharma
      Supreet Prasad Sinha
  N. Senthil Kumar
 A. Salai Nayagan
.
.
```

and so on..

Now If I want to get the names which have `Kumar` as a part, I can use simply:

```
grep -i "kumar" myfile
```

So it will return like this:

```
Saurav Kumar
    Sumeet Kumar
Punit Kumar Sharma
  N. Senthil Kumar
```

**What I want is not to display the word `Kumar` in the search result**. i,e the searched results without `Kumar` like this:

```
Saurav
    Sumeet
Punit Sharma
  N. Senthil
```

One more thing I have to use only grep to get the result not any thing else like `tr`, `sed`, `awk`, etc..

I don't know whether my question heading is appropriate or not. So I request to change it to make it more meaningful.

I will be very happy to get the solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can use negative lookbehind to _match_ the desired portion, but using `grep` you can't get the _output_ in the desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could come slightly close to result with extra new line

```
grep -P -o -i '.*(?=kumar)|(?<=kumar).*' file | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

Output

```
Saurav 
    Sumeet 
Punit 
 Sharma
  N. Senthil
```

Comment: Thank you! You almost solve the issue. And it doesn't matter if I get one extra line. I checked that it was happening only when the matching word is in between..

Comment: @SauravKumar glad that it worked for you. You gave a really good challenge!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for cannot be accomplished using `grep`.

You can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to **match** the desired portion of text using `grep`, but I don't think that you can obtain the output in the desired form.  For example, saying:

```
grep -P '\w+\b(?<!\bKumar)' yourinput
```

would result in:

```
**Saurav** Kumar
    **Sumeet** Kumar
**Punit** Kumar **Sharma**
      **Supreet Prasad Sinha**
```

The asterisks `**` around the words denoted the matched words.

However, if you were to attempt to print only the matched words, those wouldn't be really in the same line:

```
$ grep -oP '\w+\b(?<!\bKumar)' yourinput
Saurav
Sumeet
Punit
Sharma
Supreet
Prasad
Sinha
```

Using a negative lookahead, you could say:

```
grep -P '(?!Kumar\b)\b\w+' input
```

Comment: That is the problem. The scenario I've mentioned is nothing  to compared with the actual problem. I've to use `grep` anyhow, because I'm using with the options `--line-buffered`. Although I will try your answer. Hope it would work!\

Comment: Since you mention `--line-buffered`, have you explored `stdbuf`?

Comment: It is a part of `grep` command only, i,e what I want, and It is working with `--line-buffered`. But another answer looks more specific and correct.  I thank you for you great effort. :)